# How do i handle url callbacks on my serverless flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am testing a crypto payment system on my flutter app, and after generating a random address for payment, the api is supposed to notify me when the transaction has been confirmed using a callback url. I use firestore for my backend, how do i handle this callback url. I will post a copy of the documentation below.

"Insert your URL address where you want to get callbacks in create_payment request. The parameter name is ipn_callback_url. You will receive payment updates (statuses) to this URL address."

Comment: Use firebase functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone having a similar challenge, i actually solved this problem by writing a http cloud function to help me handle this, then supplied the url to the function as the callback url to the api. SO yes.... http cloud functions was a solution to this problem

Here's a very simple function that can be used:

```
exports.paymentConfirmation = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res)=>{
  const requestBody = req.body;
  const paymentStatus = requestBody.payment_status;
  console.log('this is the payment status: ' + paymentStatus);
  Promise.resolve();
 }
  res.send(null);
})
```

basically you can do anything you want with the request body you get back. In this case i just logged one of the parameters. After deploying this function to firebase, you have access to its url. Problem solved. So when there's an update from the api u subscribed to, it can send a POST request to that url and that triggers whatever code you've written in the function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).